# creating a todo list with user login and user specific lists using php, mysql, and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

basically what i have is a system where users login and they are brought to a page that shows what projects they are working on. a project is defined by having a group name, a due date, a description, and the associated class. as it stands, the code can log a user in. take the user to a page with a table, where they can enter the data that creates a new row that has all the data plugged in, but the data never gets added to the database. I'm not quite sure how to go forward; both database design and storing the variables users enter into the database so the next time that user signs in, they are able to see all the of the items they have added to their table.

databases tables:

users: ID(int)(primarykey)(AI), username(VARCHAR), password(VARCHAR)

group: ID(Int)(primarykey)(AI), name(VARCHAR)

duedate:ID(INT)(primarykey)(AI), due(DATE)

description:ID(int)(primarykey(AI), name(varchar)

class:ID(int)(primarykey)(AI), name(varchar)

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>index.php</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>OneProject</h1>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>-<a href="register.php">Register</a>-<a href="login.php">Login</a>-<a href="logout.php">Logout</a><hr />
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
            ?>
            <TABLE  BORDER="4" WIDTH="30%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6"><h2>Projects</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>group</th>
            <th>class</th>
            <th>due date</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="group" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="class" /></td>
            <td><input type="date" id="duedate" /></td>
            <td><input type ="text" id="description" /></td>
            <th><image src="green-plus-sign-hi-png.png" alt="" height="10" width="10" id="add"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var group=document.getElementById("group");
        var myClass= document.getElementById("class");
        var duedate=document.getElementById("duedate");
        var descrip=document.getElementById("description");
       $("table tr:last").after("<tr><td>"+group.value+"</td><td>"+myClass.value+"</td><td id='late'>"+duedate.value+"</td><td>"+descrip.value+"</td><td><image src='1659484_orig.png' id='delete' height='10' width= '10'>");
    });
    $("table").on("click","#delete", function(){
        $("#delete").closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: There's a lot of work that needs to be done here and I'd suggest you go back to basics with learning PHP and probably SQL, and JavaScript. Learn what each does, where they excel and what you __can't__ do with them.

As for this above: first, you don't have a `<form>` tag which also means you're not actually `POST`ing the data entered in the inputs anywhere, When you have that set up, you need to actually `INSERT` the item(s) into he database. You'll also need to write the code to retrieve the records for the logged-in user. There's more to this, but like I said you should go back to basics.

Comment: For PHP maybe start here: http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/diving-into-php-day-2/, here: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php. I think this Ben Forta book is pretty decent for SQL as well: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0672336073/?&tag=benfortascoldfus

Answer (score 1):

seems to me, you need to study a bit more in the area. check tptcat links.

how ever, if you want to learn by example, you have lots of good tutorials in the web, check for example

- this one http://tutbuzz.com/your-own-todo-list-using-php-mysql-jquery
- or http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/ajax-todo-list-jquery-php-mysql-css/
- or https://tutsplus.com/tutorial/how-to-code-a-fun-to-do-list-with-php-and-ajax/

but for me, instead of trying to mix PHP,MYSQL,CSS, HTML and jquery all together.

First, try to learn only PHP and MYSQL.

For example http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/2.html